# Creating a custom page post type just like the original "pages" post type using CPT UI

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

How can I make my custom post type (a page type) using CPT UI? What are the setting I should use? Like I need a custom "pages" section completely separate of the original "pages" section, yet it should be completely independent.

Comment: What specifically about pages do you need that you're unsure about?

Comment: How to create it, and not another blog post custom type